# Sphinxsearch + SQL Server = unknown type 'mssql'; skipping

Tags: sql-server, sphinx

I'm trying to index some data from SQL Server and getting no luck with that:

**Ubuntu 16.04**

```
apt-get install sphinxsudo add-apt-repository ppa:builds/sphinxsearch-rel22
apt-get update
apt-get install sphinxsearch
```

**/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf**

```
source src1
{
        # data source type. mandatory, no default value
        # known types are mysql, pgsql, mssql, xmlpipe, xmlpipe2, odbc
        type = mssql

        #####################################################################
        ## SQL settings (for 'mysql' and 'pgsql' types)
        #####################################################################

        # some straightforward parameters for SQL source types
        sql_host = 192.168.*.*
        sql_user = ****
        sql_pass = ****
        sql_db   = DatabaseName
        sql_port = 1433  # optional, default is 3306
        ...
}
```

**indexer --all**

```
Sphinx 2.2.9-id64-release (rel22-r5006)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'test1'...
ERROR: source 'src1': unknown type 'mssql'; skipping.
ERROR: index 'test1': failed to configure some of the sources, will not index.
```

After all I've tried to compile sphinx from sources but there is no `with-mssql` option available in configure file:

```
 Optional Packages:
  --with-PACKAGE[=ARG]    use PACKAGE [ARG=yes]
  --without-PACKAGE       do not use PACKAGE (same as --with-PACKAGE=no)
  --with-debug            compile slower debug version (default is disabled)
  --with-assert           compile optimized build but with debugging
                          assertions (default is disabled)
  --with-mysql            compile with MySQL support (default is enabled)
  --with-static-mysql     link statically with MySQL library (default is no)
  --with-mysql-includes   path to MySQL header files
  --with-mysql-libs       path to MySQL libraries
  --with-syslog           compile with possibility to use syslog for logging
                          (default is yes)
  --with-pgsql            compile with PostgreSQL support (default is
                          disabled)
  --with-static-pgsql     link statically with PostgreSQL library (default is
                          no)
  --with-pgsql-includes   path to PostgreSQL header files
  --with-pgsql-libs       path to PostgreSQL libraries
  --with-libstemmer       compile with libstemmer support (default is
                          disabled)
  --with-libexpat         compile with expat XML library suppport (default is
                          autodetect)
  --with-re2              compile with RE2 library support (default is
                          disabled)
  --with-re2-includes     path to RE2 header files
  --with-re2-libs         path to RE2 libraries
  --with-rlp              compile with RLP library support (default is
                          disabled)
  --with-iconv            compile with iconv support (default is autodetect)
  --with-unixodbc         compile with UnixODBC support (default is
                          autodetect)
```

Is there any chance to make sphinxsearch be able to index data from SQL Server? Thank you for your attention and answers! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think MSSQL driver only works on windows builds. Historically MSSQL wasnt available for linux, so the driver never been implemented on linux.

Maybe can use the ODBC driver (which I think is http://www.unixodbc.org/)

found this: http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/FreeTDS.html